# How can I express "14 less than the result of 2 times y" in Chinese?

Tags: translation

I am translating a high school math quiz for an English Language Learning student whose native language is Chinese. One of the sections on this quiz involves writing algebraic expressions for English statements. I have been able to use basic web translation tools for some of the questions, but I am having issues with the statement "14 less than the result of 2 times y," which would have the answer 2y-14.

Comment: Just from curiosity, but isnt math language the same around the world? I think 2y-14 will do.

Comment: He want's to know how to express that verbally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say :      “比y的两倍小14”.